# Bind variables to directive scope as vm without having a controller for the directive?

Tags: angularjs

The code below works fine. But can I bind anonymous and enabled to "scope as vm" without defining a controller? I don't need a controller. I just need these two variables.

I am using angular 1.4.

```
angular.
module("Settings").
directive("Settings", function SettingsDirective() {
    "use strict";

    return {
        restrict: "E",
        scope: {
            anonymous: "=",
            enabled: "=",
        },
        templateUrl: "tmpl/settings/settings-directive.html",
        controller: "SettingsController",
        controllerAs: "vm",
        bindToController: true,
    };
});
```

Comment: Use `controller: function() {}` and you'll have a controller. What's the problem in having a controller?

Comment: What happens when you remove the controller?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It might help to understand more about why you want to achieve this, instead of just using?

```
angular.
    module("Settings").
    directive("Settings", function SettingsDirective() {
        "use strict";

        return {
            restrict: "E",
            scope: {
                anonymous: "=",
                enabled: "=",
            },
            templateUrl: "tmpl/settings/settings-directive.html",
            controller: function(){}
        };
   });
```